# Linq to XML - Fetching value based on condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML as below :

```
<Nodes>
  <Node>
    <A>This is a dummy text {12345}</A>
    <B>Output Value</B>
  </Node>
  <Node>
    <A>This is another dummy text {3462832}</A>
    <B>Output Value</B>
  </Node>
</Nodes>
```

I am using Linq to XML and want to select the output value in Node 'B' if the text in Node 'A' contains the key '12345'

Please provide the inputs for the LINQ query that should be used to achieve this.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

This does exactly what you want: -

```
var nodes = from n in xml.Descendants("Node")
                         .Where(x => x.Element("A").Value.Contains("12345")) 
            select n.Element("B").Value;
```

XML sample: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Nodes>
    <Node>
        <A>This is a dummy text {12345}</A>
        <B>Output Value</B>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <A>This is a dummy text {12345}</A>
        <B>Output Value 2</B>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <A>This is another dummy text {3462832}</A>
        <B>Output Value</B>
    </Node>
</Nodes>
```

Will return: -

`Output Value`
`Output Value 2`

Comment: Thanks ! It worked. I was not using the lambda expression appropriately.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question then please consider [accepting it as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to help other users that might face a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Or in single line with LINQ and XPath:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var b = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//Node[contains(A,'12345')]/B");
```

That returns value of first found element matching conditions. If you need all matches, then use *XPathSelectElements* instead.